# Apply function on each value of parameter pack and check return values

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

Have this piece of working code:

```
template < class... Objects >
static void callNotifyOnPointerObjects ( Objects&&... objects )
{
    int arr[] = { 0, ( static_cast< void > ( objects->Notify () ), 0 )... };
    static_cast< void > ( arr );
}
```

`objects->Notify()` return value is `bool`

How can I put into bool array return values coming from execution of `objects->Notify()` and check if all values are `true`:

```
template < class... Objects >
static bool callNotifyOnPointerObjects ( Objects&&... objects )
{
    // Put in this array return values from objects->Notify () execution
    bool rc [sizeof...(objects)] = {false};
    int arr[] = { 0, ( static_cast< void > ( objects->Notify () ), 0 )... };
    static_cast< void > ( arr );
    // check if all values in rc == true and return true or false
    // return result;
}
```

Comment: Try [`std::all_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of).

Answer (score 3):

```
struct foo {
    bool Notify() const { return /* something */; }
};

template<typename... Objects>
bool callNotifyOnPointerObjects(Objects&&... objects)
{
    bool rc[]{ objects->Notify() ... };
    for (auto const &c : rc)
        if(!c) return false
    return true;
}
```

Or, instead of the `for`-loop, use [`std::all_of()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) as suggested by @n.m. in a comment:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

// ...

template<typename... Objects>
bool callNotifyOnPointerObjects(Objects&&... objects)
{
    bool rc[]{ objects->Notify() ... };
    return std::all_of(std::begin(rc), std::end(rc), [](bool b){ return b; });
}
```

However, it might be more performant to just

```
template<typename... Objects>
bool callNotifyOnPointerObjects(Objects&&... objects)
{
    return (objects->Notify() + ...) == sizeof...(objects);
}
```